# Does a 'X' in a 'Suggested Connections for Unused Pins' table on an IC data sheet mean yes or no?

Tags: datasheet

On table 2, page 6 of the [datasheet for the ST VN5E160MS-E Single-channel high-side driver](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group2/73/be/a4/20/c7/b9/4c/b0/CD00235846/files/CD00235846.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00235846.pdf) the manufacturer provides guidance on what to do with unused pins on the IC package.

Instead of a text instruction, some items are marked with an 'X' which seems to be undefined in the datasheet.

[image: 'Suggested connections for unused and not connected pins' Screenshot]

Looking at the CS_DIS pin, for example, is the manufacturer suggesting that the pin (if not used) is able to be left floating or to be placed 'Through *[sic]* 10 kΩ resistor' to ground?

Or, are they suggesting that leaving it floating is an invalid option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the table is for "what you can or cannot do with the pins", it answers the question "Can you leave them floating, or can you ground them?".

The table marks each valid combination with an X, meaning for example Yes, you can leave the output pin floating. But you cannot leave the Current sense-pin floating (because it says Not allowed" in that box).

Comment: Admittedly, a tick would be clearer than an X...

Comment: I find it odd that the table implies that an “N. C.” (Presumably “no connection”) pin can be grounded, especially since the package has **no** N. C. pins.

Comment: @DoxyLover That is indeed strange. A datasheet specifying that NC pinc can be grounded is nothing wrong, but since there is none it is rather strange. Must be some copy/paste error that no one has fixed it in the 13 years the datasheet has existed.